# How the amperage of power source is computed?

Tags: power-supply, amperage

Almost all power sources have the amperage written on them.

How does the amperage of the power source is computed?

Comment: I would have thought that the amperage of a "power source" (I assume you mean power supply) is *specified* rather than computed. Then the power supply is specifically *designed* to *supply* up to that current.

Comment: Yes, you are right but how is " designed to supply" up to that current? For example suppose they did "design" and built it, now how do they test that amperage (to see is what it has to be) before shipping it?

Answer (score 3):

A given supply's power rating is calculated or specified when it is designed (i.e. we need/want to sell a 42 Watt supply, so we will create a 42 Watt supply). It's components are chosen to **exceed** the voltage and current that the supply should normally provide, for safety reasons. Then a prototype is created and tested through various means. A simple load like a power resistor or a common motor would provide a quick test, along with more complicated tests for output fluctuations or ripple. If satisfactory, an initial run of the supply is created, goes through manufacturer testing to ensure the batch is good, then full production.

The how and why a power supply is design covers a full education in electronics and can't be boiled down easily. The same can be said for marketing and logistics of buying/selling.

Comment: As amperage (and current flow) can not exist or be computed without a circuit how do they compute the needed amperage on the paper (when making the prototype) ?

Comment: @GheorghiuAlex they ***choose*** a target amperage and voltage.

Comment: Can you provide with a link that explain this ? I do not have "full education in electronics" but I can understand simple circuits and I will (at least) try to understand more of it.

Comment: Here's a good article on EE Times http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272437 a white paper http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an104f.pdf and here's a much shorter white paper http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/appnotes/lecroy_testing_power_devices.pdf

Comment: @GheorghiuAlex those are just three links, but they are a bit technical. That's the problem, as power supply design is a very very technical process.